AWS Athena Error: Modifying Hive table rows is only supported for transactional tables
I am not able to perform delete operation on row in AWS Athena tables. It is throwing below error as:
NOT_SUPPORTED: Modifying Hive table rows is only supported for transactional tables
This query ran against the "some database" database, unless qualified by the query.

Below is the code I used in my lambda to create table
if (!tableExists) {
        try {
            await glue.createTable({
                DatabaseName: DATABASE,
                TableInput: {
                    Name: TABLE,
                    StorageDescriptor: {
                        Columns: columns,
                        Location: 's3://some-bucket/some-table/',
                        InputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
                        OutputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat',
                        SerdeInfo: {
                            SerializationLibrary: 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
                        }
                    },
                    TableType: 'EXTERNAL_TABLE'
                }
            }).promise();
        } catch (err) {
            logger.error(`Error creating Glue table: ${err}`);
            throw err;
        }
    }

Any leads would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

External Table is read only table, Which means thing that you stored in Glue is only the metadata, not for row by row.
So you can't do transactional query type by athena.
So i suggest you to switch data into ICEBERG, or you directly delete row in s3.
